# PHP, Shorthand, If..Else using Ternary Operators

Tags: php, operators, ternary

Is there a oneliner for this? A nice Ternary OP?

```
$F_NAME = $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME'];
if(isset($_POST['F_NAME'])) {$F_NAME = $_POST['F_NAME'];}
```

Basically "If the POST is sent, show that, even if the post is empty, otherwise grab the value from the session, but only if the post was not set or empty"

Really splitting hairs here...

looking for something like this:

```
$F_NAME = ? ($F_NAME ? isset($_POST['F_NAME']) : $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME']);
```

Comment: $F_NAME = (isset($_POST['F_NAME']) ? $_POST['F_NAME'] : $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME']);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its supposed to be:

```
(conditions) ? true : false
   satisfies <--^      ^----> did not satisfy
```

So this equates into:

```
$F_NAME = isset($_POST['F_NAME']) ? $_POST['F_NAME'] : $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME'];
```

Comment: nice. thank you.
so it seems: (condition ? true result : false result)

Comment: yes, having `?` like the one you have `($F_NAME ? isset($_POST['F_NAME'])` inside the condition is incorrect

Comment: AWESOME.
I tossed that into a foreach with the {variable} set option

`
foreach ($_SESSION['USR'] as $key => $value) {
 ${$key}  = (isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : $_SESSION['USR'][$key]);
}`

Comment: @ChristianŽagarskas yes that should work just fine if you'd like to check for the values if it exist first. glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

As Ghost response, or even shorter

```
$F_NAME = $_POST['F_NAME'] ? : $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME'];
```

Comment: thank you! Ghost however is correct, there are 2 conditions I must satisfy, the statement can not default to $_SESSION['USR']['F_NAME']

Comment: But you get the picture on shorthand