# If statement inside variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to put the following inside a php variable.

I dont know what im doing wrong here :

```
$cartlink='<a class="cart-contents" href="'.$shoppingcart.'" title="View your shopping cart">' + if ( $count > 0 ) {<span class="cart-contents-count">"'.$count.'"</span></a>} + '</a>';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, Shorthand, If..Else using Ternary Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814065/php-shorthand-if-else-using-ternary-operators)

Comment: are you experienced in php :|

Comment: @Andrew no he's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string concat is a bit off, and PHP uses dots `.` to concat variables together, not `+` like JavaScript.

There are a couple of ways you could achieve this, via a ternary operator

```
$cartlink = '<a class="cart-contents" href="'.$shoppingcart.'" title="View your shopping cart">'.($count > 0 ? '<span class="cart-contents-count">"'.$count.'"</span></a>' : "").'</a>';
```

Or string concatination via a normal if

```
$cartlink = '<a class="cart-contents" href="'.$shoppingcart.'" title="View your shopping cart">';
if ($count > 0)
    $cartlink .= '<span class="cart-contents-count">"'.$count.'"</span></a>';
$cartlink .= '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use if statement like that. Instead use inline version: `(condition ? true_case : false_case)`

You can write variables directly into quotes
`echo "Value: $variable";`

```
$cartlink="<a class='cart-contents' href='$shoppingcart' title='View your shopping cart'>" . ( $count > 0 ? "<span class='cart-contents-count'>$count</span></a>" : "" ) . '</a>';
```

edit: in php whole ternary operator have to be surrounded by brackets to work properly