# How can i write this if condition inside the href tag?

Tags: php

I don't know how to write the `if-condition` inside the `Href`.The `href` is written in the `PHP tags`. and it gives me an error that `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Portal\admin\pages\ajax\EditDeleteAssignment.php on line 84`

This is my code...

```
<?php     $data .= '<tfooter>
            <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;" href="?pageno=1" >First</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo "disabled" } ">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;" href="'.if($pageno <= 1){ echo "#"; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); }.'">Prev</a>
             </table>';
                echo $data;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Ternary If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814065/php-shorthand-if-else-using-ternary-operators)

```
($pageno <= 1) ? "#" : "?pageno=" . ($pageno - 1) .
```

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;" href="'.($pageno <= 1) ? "#" : "?pageno=" . ($pageno - 1).'"> can i write like this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not necessarily writing this *in an `href`*, you're writing it *in a string*.  PHP doesn't care what that HTML is, as far as it's concerned it's just a string.  Simplified to:

```
$data .= '...' . if($pageno <= 1){ echo "#"; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); }. '...';
```

The syntax problem here is that you have multiple code lines, even multiple code blocks, on a single line of code.  Fortunately, for simple conditional statemens which result in just a result to output, there's the ternary conditional operator.  Something like this:

```
$data .= '...' . ($pageno <= 1 ? "#" : ("?pageno=" . ($pageno - 1))) . '...';
```

Notice the components thereing:

```
$pageno <= 1                 // <-- the condition being checked
?                            // <-- the start of the operator, what's before it is the condition
"#"                          // <-- the result if true
:                            // <-- the second part of the operator, basically the "else"
("?pageno=" . ($pageno - 1)) // <-- the result if false
```

Note also the various parentheses used.  Combining multiple concatenation operators throughout this conditional expression could easily confuse the parser or the programmer.  Better to be explicit about the order of operations here.

Comment: could you please write the whole code? i do this but it not working for me.

Comment: @SyedWaqasAhmad: What did you try and what isn't working"?  "It's not working" could literally mean anything, and you may have other problems elsewhere in your code.  I did "write the whole code" except for the excessively long string literals.  You can copy/paste your own string literals there.